# OpenCV does not recognize a camera in BeagleBone

Tags: c++, opencv, beagleboard

I have written the following code to use a camera, [PlayStation Eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EyeToy), via [BeagleBone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard#BeagleBone_Black):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void inputSetup(int setup);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CvCapture *capture;
    Mat img;

    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
    if (capture){
        printf("mmm...\n");
        inputSetup(1);
        img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    }

    while (1);

    return 0;
}

void inputSetup(int setup)
{
    static struct termios oldt, newt;
    if (setup) {
        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
        newt = oldt;
        newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
        tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    }
    else {
        tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it does not recognize the camera since the code does not go into the first "if" (the one that print "mmm..."). I have already tried with "capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);", but it does not work neither.

I am compiling the code with the following command:

```
g++ -Wall -g -o CamaraTest CamaraTest.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest OpenCV [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) repository. There were issues in the camera drivers, but most of them have been fixed already.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am kind of new working with repositories and installing them in Linux, can you send me a link or any info to know how to get the latest version of openCV and how to install it (specifically for Angstrom distro)? I am currently using the libraries of openCV that came with the distro.